# Issue with my php website email form

Tags: php, forms, email, web, contacts

I have a website in which I just want a contact form that will take the comments from the user and then send the email to me. I have the following html code:

```
        <form action="emailform.php" method="post" name="contactform" role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group left-inner-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group left-inner-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group left-inner-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
                        <input name="telephone" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="form-group left-inner-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
                        <textarea name="message" rows="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Message..."></textarea><br>
                        <a><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Send</button></a>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default right">Reset</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- row -->
        </form>
```

And I have the php code "emailform.php" here:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "george@lehaftech.com";
    $email_subject = "PILLAR 360 Inquiry";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $name = $_POST['input_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['input_email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['input_tel']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

      if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php

}
?>
```

When I use the contact form to send an email, I just get a blank page loading and the email doesn't get sent... So the error codes aren't showing and the success line isn't showing..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add name for the submit button

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Send</button>
```

Also change part of the code as below

```
// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['message'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}


$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['message']; // required
```

Hope these changes fix issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I looked at PHP - so this might not be an issue - but in your form - your submit button has a `value="Submit"` - ie : capitalised - but in your php page - it is looking for "submit" ie - not capitalised:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...
```

And therefor it is missing the error handling block within the php page.

You need to change eitehr the html or the php to ensure the two are the same

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {...
```

Also - it seems that your form input names do not match the POST values you are using in the php page

```
$name = $_POST['input_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['input_email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['input_tel']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['message']; // required
```

You only have the inputs as "name", "email" etc in the form

```
$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['message']; // required
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code to your HTML File right after the form tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="send">
```

and in your PHP File change:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'send') {...
```

Hope this helps.